# What concept allows a container to be usable in a range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, c++-concepts

I have a container which is actually a `std::shared_ptr< std::vector< Element > >`. I wrapped this type into a `MyVector` class because I do not want people to mess the things up with the pointer:

```
class MyVector
{
    std::shared_ptr< std::vector< Element > > m_vector;
};
```

I want to be able to use `MyVector` into a range-based `for` loop like this:

```
int main( )
{
    MyVector vector;

    // ...

    for( const auto& element : vector )
    { 
        // ...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So now I have to redirect to the internal pointer the correct functions in order to make it work. To which C++ Concept must `MyVector` be compliant?
And how can I achieve the result that when the internal `std::shared_ptr` is `nullptr`, `MyVector` behaves exactly like an empty `std::vector` (so that it will not crash on a range-based loop, but will just make no iteration at all)?

Comment: Why do you have a pointer to a vector? That is almost always wrong. What problem is it supposed to solve?

Comment: As for your problem, have you checked e.g. [this range-for reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is coming from the API I am using. No idea whatsoever :/

Comment: Ranged based for is not based off C++ Concepts, which is a proposal being considered for standardization.  Do you mean that, or just want it to work?

Answer (score -2):

To answer your question take a look at the explanation of range based for loops as in the [cppreference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    auto __begin = begin_expr ;
    auto __end = end_expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
    } 
}
```

And this quote

> If range_expression is an expression of a class type C that has a member named begin and/or a member named end (regardless of the type or accessibility of such member), then `begin_expr` is `__range.begin()` and `end_expr` is `__range.end()`;

1. So firstly you need to provide a `begin()` method, an `end()` method.  Both should return an instance of some sort of iterator class (they can be of different types!)
2. The iterator returned by `begin()` should support the preincrement operator and the dereference operator as inferred from the explanation above.
3. And finally the iterators returned by `begin()` and `end()` should be comparable with a `!=`.

Comment: @Curious and how can I achieve the effect that when the internal pointer is `nullptr`, the container behaves like an empty `std::vector` (for the range-loop purpose)? I can easily forward `begin()` and `end()` when the pointer is available, but I have no clue when the pointer is not there.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 make `end()` return an iterator which is initialized with `nullptr` and in the case where your container is empty have `begin()` do the same.  And then in the comparison operator compare whether the two have the same pointer, if so they compare equal

Comment: @nyarlathotep108: Have a static empty vector private to the class.  If the pointer is null, then begin and end can return the begin/end of this static.