# Is there a concept in the standard library that tests for usability in ranged for loops

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, ranged-loops

There are a number of different ways, that make a type/class usable in a ranged for loop. An overview is for example given on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Explanation):

> `range-expression` is evaluated to determine the sequence or range to iterate.
> Each element of the sequence, in turn, is dereferenced and is used to initialize the
> variable with the type and name given in range-declaration.
>
> `begin_expr` and `end_expr` are defined as follows:
>
> - If `range-expression` is an expression of array type, then `begin_expr` is `__range`
>   and `end_expr` is (`__range` + `__bound`), where `__bound` is the number of elements
>   in the array (if the array has unknown size or is of an incomplete type, the program
>   is ill-formed)
> - If `range-expression` is an expression of a class type `C` that has both a member
>   named `begin` and a member named `end` (regardless of the type or accessibility of
>   such member), then `begin_expr` is `__range.begin()` and `end_expr` is `__range.end()`
> - Otherwise, `begin_expr` is `begin(__range)` and `end_expr` is `end(__range)`, which
>   are found via argument-dependent lookup (non-ADL lookup is not performed).

If I want to use a ranged for loop say in a function template, I want to constrain the type to be usable in a ranged for loop, to trigger a compiler error with a nice "constraint not satisfied" message. Consider the following example:

```
template<typename T>
requires requires (T arg) {
  // what to write here ??
}
void f(T arg) {
    for ( auto e : arg ) {
    }
}
```

Obviously for a generic function I want to support all of the above listed ways, that a type can use to make itself ranged for compatible.

This brings me to my questions:

1. Is there a better way than manually combining all the different ways into a custom
   concept, is there some standard library concept that I can use for that? In the
   [concepts library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts), there is no such thing. And if there is really no such thing,
   is there a reason for that?
2. If there is no library/builtin concept for that, how am I supposed to implement such
   thing. What really puzzles me, is how to test for members `begin` and `end`
   *regardless of the type or accessibility of such member* (second bullet in the qouted
   list). A requires clause that tests for example for the existence of a `begin()`
   member fails if `begin()` is private, but the ranged for loop would be able to use
   the type regardless of that.

**Note**
I am aware of the following two questions:

- [What concept allows a container to be usable in a range-based for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967778/what-concept-allows-a-container-to-be-usable-in-a-range-based-for-loop)
- [How to make my custom type to work with "range-based for loops"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164567/how-to-make-my-custom-type-to-work-with-range-based-for-loops)

but neither of them really answers my question.

Comment: `std::begin`/`std::end` works for arrays, and will call the `begin/end` members if they exists. So that should cover all 3 cases already.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the thing about private `begin`/ `end`. When the type has private `begin` and `end` then the range based for loop will attempt to use them and not fall back to `std::begin` and `std::end`. Hence the range based for loop is not able to use such type: https://godbolt.org/z/3dMPaPb57

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number that is actually a good point. Private `begin`/`end` members will cause the ranged for loop to not compile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like what you need is [`std::ranges::range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range) which requires the expressions `ranges::begin(t)` and `ranges::end(t)` to be well-formed.

Where `ranges::begin` is defined in [[range.access.begin]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/range.access.begin):

> The name `ranges​::​begin` denotes a customization point object. Given a subexpression `E` with type `T`,
> let t be an lvalue that denotes the reified object for `E`. Then:
>
> - If `E`
>   is an rvalue and `enable_­borrowed_­range<remove_­cv_­t<T>>` is `false`,
>   `ranges​::​begin(E)` is ill-formed.
> - Otherwise, if `T` is an array type
>   and `remove_­all_­extents_­t<T>` is an incomplete type,
>   `ranges​::​begin(E)` is ill-formed with no diagnostic required.
> - Otherwise, if T is an array type, `ranges​::​begin(E)` is
>   expression-equivalent to `t + 0`.
> - Otherwise, if `auto(t.begin())` is a
>   valid expression whose type models `input_­or_­output_­iterator`,
>   `ranges​::​begin(E)` is expression-equivalent to `auto(t.begin())`.
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a class or enumeration type and `auto(begin(t))` is a
>   valid expression whose type models `input_­or_­output_­iterator` with
>   overload resolution performed in a context in which unqualified lookup
>   for `begin` finds only the declarations
>
>   ```
>   void begin(auto&) = delete; 
>   void begin(const auto&) = delete;
>   ```
>
>   then `ranges​::​begin(E)` is
>   expression-equivalent to `auto(begin(t))` with overload resolution
>   performed in the above context.
> - Otherwise, `ranges​::​begin(E)` is
>   ill-formed.

That is to say, it will not only perform specific operations on the array type but also decide whether to invoke member function `range.begin()` or free function `begin(range)` based on the validity of the expression, this already covers the behavior described by the so-called *range-expression*. And [`ranges::end`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/range.access.end) follows similar rules. So I think you can simply do

```
template<std::ranges::range T>
void f(T arg) {
  for (auto&& e : arg) { // guaranteed to work
  }
}
```

It should be noted that `ranges::begin` requires that the returned type must model [`input_or_output_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_or_output_iterator), and `ranges::end` also requires that the returned type must model [`sentinel_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/sentinel_for) type returned by `ranges::begin`, so that `T` is enough to be a `range`. The *range-expression* does not have such constraints,  it only checks the validity of the expression, so a minimal type that can use a *range-based for loop* could be

```
struct I {
  int operator*();
  I& operator++();
  bool operator!=(const I&) const;
};

struct R {
  I begin();
  I end();
};

for (auto x : R{}) { } // well-formed
```

But I don't think you're interested in such a case since `I` is not sufficient to constitute a valid iterator.

Comment: It even has a similar name :) Totally makes sense, that a "range" is required to be used in a "ranged for loop".